# Removing a Custom Item From Inventory

Tags: java, bukkit

```
ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Material.PAPER);
ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
meta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GREEN + "$5 Banknote");
item.setItemMeta(meta);

if (player.getInventory().contains(item))
{
    player.getInventory().removeItem(item);
    player.updateInventory();
    econ.depositPlayer(player, 5);
    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "You have deposited a $5 banknote and $5 has been added to your account!");
}
```

So, I have this command that if run, it is supposed to take the item (banknote) out of your inventory and give you money in return. It works if the item is not stacked, but if it is stacked, it does not recognize the stack as the item (banknote).

What am I doing wrong here? How can I make it so even if it is stacked, it will recognize it, and remove a single item from that stack?

Answer (score 1):

The `contains(ItemStack)` method implemented in the `CraftInventory` class iterates through the contents of the inventory and uses the `equals(Object)` method to compare each `ItemStack` to the one that you're looking for. The `equals(Object)` method for `ItemStack`s compares amount, material (or type), durability and metadata. When you create a new `ItemStack` by only providing a `Material`, the `ItemStack` will have a default amount of 1, and that item will not equal any `ItemStack`s containing multiple banknotes.

The method by which you are removing the banknote from the inventory would work just fine, but the line `if (player.getInventory().contains(item)) {` stops the code from executing if it doesn't find at least one inventory slot containing a *single* banknote (because of the way the `contains(ItemStack)` method works as explained above). So, as your code stands right now, it would even remove the item correctly from slots containing stacked (multiple) banknotes if the inventory also somewhere contained a single banknote (but it will not work if the inventory only contains stacked banknotes).

To fix this you can simple remove the if check. To still know whether the removal of the item was successful (AKA if at least one banknote was found and subsequently removed), you can check the return type of the `removeItem(ItemStack)` method, which is a HashMap containing the items that the method was *not* able to remove. If the operation was successful, the map will be empty, if not, it will contain the single banknote that you tried to remove.

Here is what the code would look like:

```
HashMap<Integer, ItemStack> result = player.getInventory().removeItem(item); // Item is the banknote with an amount of 1

if (result.isEmpty()) { // Removal operation was successful, send player confirmation and deposit
    econ.depositPlayer(player, 5);
    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "You have deposited a $5 banknote and $5 have been added to your acccount!");
}

// Optionally you can add an else statement if you want to tell the player that no banknotes were found
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works :D

Comment: Sweet, glad I could help! Since this answer solved your problem, could you please accept it (so that it's not an unanswered question)?

Answer (score 0):

get the players inventory and check if a item exists with the custom itemmeta you set to it itemmeta stands for like custom name or enchantments or a lore basicly yeah

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that `contains` method uses `equals` and `equals` is implemented in way to take item size into account. So I would just manually iterate over this collection to find ItemStack of this specific item.